# Google Maps API Javascript v3 Not Executing Code Block that attempts GeoLocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting this code block to get the geolocation of the client.. I looked at online resources and followed the examples to the tee, but for some reason it doesn't execute anything below:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){...}):
```

it will not display the :

```
alert('getting position');
```

I have already checked to see if google api is loaded

```
$('#rsvpWeddingSubmit').on('click',function(){
    if ($('#geolocation').prop('checked')){
        var pos;
        if (navigator.geolocation){
             alert('in navigator');
             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                alert('getting position');
                pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                alert(pos);
              }, function(){
                    handleNoGeolocation(true);
                    alert('true');
                 });
               }
               else{
                   handleNoGeolocation(false);
                   alert('true');
                }
  }

//$("#weddingForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: Put a basic alert above if ($('#geolocation').prop('checked')) And then move it down until you find something you don't expect.

Comment: it alerts (in navigator) and passes both click and prop. I have done tests that navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition does exist, but it just isn't working..